# R regular expression - extracting a multiple specific values after a specific word

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to create a set of variables by extracting values from a string of characters in R.

I have a variable with the following format:

```
{"name":"John Smith","employee_id":"AB001","email":"johnsmith@abc.com"},{"name":"Sarah John","employee_id":"AB002","email":"sarahjohn@abc.com"},{"name":"Chris Lee","employee_id":"AB003","email":"chrislee@abc.com"},{"name":"Brian Johns","employee_id":"AB004","email":"brianjohns@abc.com"}
```

I would like extract all the employee_id(s) and create a varaible for each of them.

What I would like from the above example,

| Employee ID1 | Employee ID2 | Employee ID3 | Employee ID4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB001 | AB002 | AB003 | AB004 |

Any suggestions/directions would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: that's json, use a json parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in JSON format, so you should not use regex to parse that data. There are packages in R that you can use to parse JSON data. I'll show you how to handle your data using the packages `jsonlite`.

The first step is to make sure that your data is valid data. The pieces in curly brackets are so-called JSON objects and since you have several of them, you should combine them into an array. This can be done by enclosing your string in square brackets:

```
data <- '{"name":"John Smith","employee_id":"AB001","email":"johnsmith@abc.com"},{"name":"Sarah John","employee_id":"AB002","email":"sarahjohn@abc.com"},{"name":"Chris Lee","employee_id":"AB003","email":"chrislee@abc.com"},{"name":"Brian Johns","employee_id":"AB004","email":"brianjohns@abc.com"}'
json_data <- paste0("[", data, "]")
```

This can now easily be parsed with `jsonlite`:

```
library(jsonlite)
table <- fromJSON(json_data)
table
##          name employee_id              email
## 1  John Smith       AB001  johnsmith@abc.com
## 2  Sarah John       AB002  sarahjohn@abc.com
## 3   Chris Lee       AB003   chrislee@abc.com
## 4 Brian Johns       AB004 brianjohns@abc.com
```

In order to get at the employee IDs, just extract the column:

```
table$employee_id
## [1] "AB001" "AB002" "AB003" "AB004"
```

Comment: if I have just one as given in an example, your answer works perfectly fine! But if I have another let's say data2 <- '{"name":"John Smith","employee_id":"AB001","email":"johnsmith@abc.com"},{"name":"Brian Johns","employee_id":"AB004","email":"brianjohns@abc.com"}' I'm getting the following error "parse error: trailing garbage" how could I fix this? Also I'm wanting to treat each data as one obs if that makes sense? Thanks! FYI - I have up to 399 observations in this format..

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add [ at the beginning and ] at the end? I get the same error massage, when I omit them. I don't understand what you mean by treating "each data as one obs".

Comment: How are those strings organised atm? In a list?

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("[", data2, "]"))` works for me with the new data, too. @Brian, what are we missing? The code in the answer works there, too.